# MySQL - use other query condition, if another query condition returns no results

Tags: mysql

function `rand();` work slow when have millions rows, 
I have table *'banners'*

```
id       image    type
1         name     1
2         name     4
3         name     76
19999999  name     3
```

need to select

```
select * from banners where type = 1 order by rand() limit 1
```

if no result then

```
select * from banners where type = 3 order by rand() limit 1
```

if no result then

```
select * from banners order by rand() limit 1
```

I try

```
select * from (
        (select * from banners where type = 1 order by rand() limit 1) union
        (select * from banners where type = 3 order by rand() limit 1) union
        (select * from banners order by rand() limit 1)
) as r limit 1
```

but is very slow!

Comment: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: unless you have very good reasons not to, always use `union all`, not just `union`

Comment: That is doing 3 full-table-scans for the subqueries, then doing a _trivial_ de-dup of the 3 rows they produced.  @ysth - _this_ case is not a good argument for `UNION ALL`.

Comment: To clarify one of your comments, please augment the existing example and/or add a second example.

Comment: @RickJames yes, it makes no significant difference in this case.  but in other cases, union distinct can perform horribly or produce results you don't expect if you don't know it is the default.  as a matter of education, union all should always be used unless you truly want union distinct

Comment: Your current "I try" is flawed in that you get one of the three choices randomly.  The verbiage implies you want to give preference to type=1?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your queries:

```
select *
from banners
order by type=1 desc, type=3 desc, rand()
limit 1;
```

but that's still likely to have to read the entire table.

Comment: thanks but for me this get random just where type=1

Comment: isn't that what you wanted?  to always return a type=1 if there are any type 1s?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from banners 
order by Case 
when Type=1 then 1 
when Type=3 then 2 
else 3 
end asc, rand()
limit 1;
```

Comment: That requires one full table scan plus a temp table with 2 columns, a sort.  (And you forgot `LIMIT 1`).  ysth builds on your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `INDEX(type)`?  If so, that *might* help your first 2 `SELECTs`.

Provide `SHOW INDEXES`.  It may indicate that the "cardinality" of type is such that it will 'always' or 'never' do a table scan.  Also, provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each case.

If the index is useful *and* there are not many rows with `type=1`, that query will be relatively fast.  Etc.

[*This*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random) discusses several ways to *efficiently* pick a random row.  See which one applies for each of your 3 cases.  Then write a Stored Routine that works something like

```
BEGIN
    ... type=1
    IF a row found
        RETURN...
    ... type=1
    IF a row found
        RETURN...
    Return a random row from the whole table
END
```